# Cannot find module when importing own knex FsMigrations implementation

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-modules, tsconfig

I'm having an issue with importing a custom implementation of knex FsMigrations in my TypeScript project. The custom implementation is located in ./src/types/custom-migrator/index.d.ts

```
    import path from 'path';

    declare module 'custom-migrator' {
        import { FsMigrations } from 'knex/lib/migrations/migrate/sources/fs-migrations';

        export class CustomFsMigrations extends FsMigrations {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

My tsconfig.json file has the following configurations

```
    {
        "compilerOptions":{
            "baseUrl":".",
            "paths":{
                "custom-migrator":[
                    "./src/types/custom-migrator"
                ]
            },
            "sourceMap":true,
            "esModuleInterop":true,
            "allowJs":true,
            "module":"CommonJS",
            "moduleResolution":"node",
            "allowSyntheticDefaultImports":true,
            "lib":[
                "ES2022"
            ],
            "outDir":"./build",
            "target":"ES2022",
            "strict":true,
            "skipLibCheck":true,
            "strictNullChecks":true,
            "noImplicitAny":true,
            "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames":true,
            "typeRoots":[
                "./src/types"
            ],
            "resolveJsonModule":true
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to import CustomFsMigrations in src/database/index.ts:

```
    import { CustomFsMigrations } from 'custom-migrator';
```

However, when I try to compile the project, I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'custom-migrator'
```

I have already set up the baseUrl and paths configurations in tsconfig.json to map the custom-migrator module to the correct path, but the error persists. How can I properly import the CustomFsMigrations class from the custom-migrator module?